# SharePoint 2016 error on site collection creation

Tags: site-collection, 2016

When I am trying to create site collection in SharePoint 2016 new server I am getting user cannot be found error. I have added myself as site collection administrator in Central Administration site collection administrators. I have ran all the CU from April to August (April 2017 CU-KB3178718, May 2017 CU-KB3191880, June 2017 CU-KB3203432, July 2017 CU-KB3213544, Aug 2017 CU-KB4011049) but still facing same issue as shown below. I have been added with full access on SQL data base permissions as well.[image]

> Couldn't get settings from site settings manager. Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site http://pddvsppspd10:80/
>   could not be found in the Web application SPWebApplication
>   Name=WSS_Developer2016_SPD10.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean
>   contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri,
>   Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid&
>   contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone&
>   zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName,
>   Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String&
>   appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String&
>   appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean
>   contextSite, Bool...  94184d9e-585f-90e1-a678-178e51faf34c ...ean
>   swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean
>   contextSite, SPUserToken userToken)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl, SPUserToken
>   userToken)     at

Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPAllUserClaimProvider.IsEveryoneClaimEnabledInTenantSetting(Uri context)    94184d9e-585f-90e1-a678-178e51faf34c

[image]

Comment: Did you ran the config wizard? whats your farm topology? any special authentication? try to find the correlation id in uls log

Comment: Yes did ran the configuration wizard for every CU . its just a standalone server for developer. Correlation id shows this in uls logs as updated in the main question above. i have updated the authentication image as well above int he question

Comment: are you creating root level site collection or 2nd level (/sites/name)? you are using the domain account to configure the farm?

Comment: creating root level site collection . used the farm account

Comment: Both error are telling different story, how u enter user name domain\user name? Is the user resolved in the primary admin field?

Comment: yes it has been resolved.

Comment: Your web application running farm admin account or any other account?

Comment: Farm admin account

Comment: i ran configuration wizard after every CU installation. Do i need to re-run the wizard after everything is done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73552/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-splearner).